# By default checkbox should be checked on any webpage

Tags: user-interface, google-chrome-extension, settings, google-chrome-devtools

As a user I have to checkmark many checkboxes in a webpage frequently. so I just want to make checkbox by default checked when ever page loads. Is there any settings we can do chrome. or any injector with the help of extension.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called Check All. It works pretty well:

Here is the link for that : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/check-all/nnbihdpkeohjdfncchjhidbbonnihaob?hl=en

Comment: that is again manual effort every time. anything else please :)